# Visual Attribute in Oracle Forms Personalization

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm having a problem with Forms Personalization, I'm a beginner in Oracle EBS and Forms Personalization. I need to change my item background color, but when I use the property `'background-color'`, it changes every the column. I want just the item, cause it was verified already in my condition. I found in the internet, people recommending to use the property `'VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE(INSTANCE-ITEM)'`, but I don't know how to use it. What should I put in `'Value'`?

Maybe pictures will help you to help me LOL.

[image: Forms Personalization 1]
[image: Forms Personalization 2]

PS: I'm using the ORACLE EBS 11g

HELP MEEE <3

Comment: How this is currently written, this appears as a Super User question as its asking for personalizing and/or configuration of software applications. If your question is seeking debug help, please provide code and input and output of said code.

Comment: I know Forms & I don't know EBS nor its personalization.

Anyway: if you want to modify properties for a single item in a tabular form, you should use `SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY` built-in. See if you can use it, somewhere (possibly in a PRE-TEXT-ITEM or similar trigger).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use it. What you have to do is to know the list of Visual Attributes the forms has defined. Open the Oracle Form and go to section: "Visual Attributes" you will see there a complete list of Visual Attributes.
For example: DATA_DRILLDOWN has a green foreground color, DATA_WARNING has a yellow background
So, what you have to do is to put one of those names in the forms personalization.
Hope this helps.